# How to change grid rows and columns on view change in XAML

Tags: xaml

I have created 3 x 4 Grid in XAML in Landscape view mode. Means 3 rows and 4 columns. Now on view change to portrait i want to make it 4 x 3 means 4 rows and 3 columns. How to do it.
Plz help me to do it.
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve it using code behind.

I made two grids one with 3 * 4 and one with 4 * 3 
 and on size_changed event of page identify the applicationViewstate and show hide the required grid

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure as to what you are meaning by how to do it, but to define new grid rows and columns would be:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

This creates a 4x3 grid panel where the widths and heights could be changed to a predetermined size or a *. If this isn't what you are looking for let me know.

Comment: Thanx but i know how to define rows and columns but i want to change it runtime on change of view.

Comment: have you tried creating resource dictionaries and switching them at runtime?